# Not able to verify text after login with selenium Webdriver script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate login functionality with `selenium webdriver` using `TestNG` framework. I want to verify the text after login like `Hi [username@gmail.com]`.

This is the order in which links are present on page :

```
TrackOrder | Notification | Singnup | Login
```

My method of doing:
I clicked on Login (login window appears) and I sign in. After login 
the order in which links are present on page are :

```
TrackOrder | Notification | Hi[username@gmail.com]
```

For verifying text after login :
I am extracting the `xPath` of web element `Hi[username@gmail.com]` and using `getText()` method to verify actual and expected value.

Actual problem:
As soon as I run script , it logs in successfully but when I extract the text of web element it is printing `signup`. Though login is done successfully why is it showing up `singup`?

Comment: How are u getting the username element in script? Can u provide the code u tried?

Comment: I am reading username from excel sheet using dataProvider

Comment: The reason is that Selenium is asynchronous.  It queues up all the requests and then goes through them when it decides.  The only way you can control this is to wait for a call back from selenium which says 'the GetText' you just queued is now done and here's the value.  The value is sent to you in the callback parameter.

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Are there invisible elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for printing signup maybe that either the XPath you gave, is not explicitly identifying the username element and just give the element next to Notification element, or the signup element text is changing to username text after login.

So, better to create unique XPath for your element and wait for some time before using getText() method.

Thread.sleep() can be used if the text of the element is changing on login as selenium will execute the method before the change in text value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Absolute Xpath of the Web Element.